# ¿Como puedo añadir código php a través de un append de js?

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
 var html = '<div class="cont-principal" style="background: url('+datos.f_background_media+') no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

<div class="cont-info"><div class="panel-info">

<img src="'+datos.f_thumbnails_media+'"><br><form action="#" method="post">

<div class="selectTemp"><select name="temporadas" id="tempo-all">

</select></div></form><h1>'+datos.f_name_media+'</h1>

<div class="synopsis" id="info">
<p id="synopsis-id">
</p>
</div>
<h3>Año:</h3>
<p>'+datos.f_year_media+'</p>

<h3>Categoria:</h3>

<p> '+datos.f_name_subcategory+'</p>

<br>
</div>

</div>

<div class="cont-video"><div class="panel-video" id="capt-panel"><?php capserie(); ?>

</div></div></div>';
    $(".series-temp").append(html);
```

Este seria el código, en el div con clase "panel-video" es donde tengo la función, pero el resultado es que sale comentado en el DOM. hay alguna forma de hacerlo? o algún otro método?

Comment: Qué es lo qué hace tu función de `php`?

Comment: me trae un lista de links de "X" temporada de una serie, la cuestion es que cuando se pega el codigo en el DOM, el codigo php me lo comenta.

Comment: Puedes utilizar ajax para traer los links que necesites y concatenarlos como lo haces con `datos.`.

Comment: No puedes ejecutar código del servidor (PHP) desde el cliente (JS) sin más. Sería catastrotifco. Para esto se usa Ajax, que sirve para enviar peticiones al servidor desde el cliente, pero el archivo que se llama está en el servidor, se le mandan los datos, éste los recibe y los procesa y devuelve una respuesta.